# Diversity disambiguation Q&A - do we need a new SE for cultural differencies and misunderstandings and their disambiguation?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

Diversity is a great fun, sometimes puzzling, sometimes embarrassing, often totally absurdous but anyway you can learn a lot about other (sub)cultures and actually your own too.

Same things familiar and clear to you could have completely different "codes" in other (sub)cultures. Note this does not have to be bound to a specific region.

Just a few examples which could make good questions in this context, not only in terms of language disambiguation:

- Is it correct that Russians say *na zdorovje* for cheers?
- How comes one colleague's name means in other's language exactly "who beats children?"
- Is it polite or impolite in culture X to tell guests that they should leave as it gets late?
- Is there a culture where you say "hello" by *spitting* on people? / Why did my Masai colleague asked to spit at him at our workplace during his afterwork birthday party last night?
- Every wondered that color of your teen child's shoe laces could express some specific message?
- Could it be that a friend a colleague behaves in a strange way because of the cultural superstition you never heard of?
- Is it okay not to have a separate BBQ device for people who are vegan or doing Ramadan?

I am sorry if you might find #3 and #4 embarassing but this is exactly why I've raised this question.

These are real life examples!

- To 3. There have been two families in my friend circle who suffered a long night embarrasment because in guests' cultures it was impolite to leave by themselves, and guests' culture expected guests to leave by themselves.
- To 4. Check this link: http://creativecultureint.com/spitting-to-show-respect

I think anybody who has lived/worked in international/expat contexts, either has experiences in binational relationships, either compared youth/gender subcultures will think of many other examples and situations.

Based on the answers and votes, I will see whether an Area 51 request would make sense or not.

This question is not a duplicate because the effort for a new site proposal requires in my eyes getting an impression whether it's worth it or not before stepping in a more formal process.

Comment: it's tempting to think the question is trolling when example 4. seems highly improbable

Comment: I suggest that the [website Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) handles these sorts of questions fairly well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA no these are real life examples!! 3. There have been two families who suffered a long night embarrasment because in guests' cultures it was impolite to leave by themselves, and guests' culture expected guests to leave by themselves. 4. https://creativecultureint.com/spitting-to-show-respect/

Comment: I meant 4, I corrected it

Comment: @Mari-LouA #4 is real as well

Comment: @Mari-LouA for national/regional cultural differences, yes. What about subcultures?

Comment: You could probably Google the answers for those trivia type questions. If you want to set up a new site, you can propose one by visiting **area51** https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/3/culture

Comment: `"... requires in my eyes getting an impression whether it's worth it or not before stepping in a more formal process.".` You can take a chance and go to Area 51 without *getting an impression*, you *could* read there about the best ways to move forward, or you can know already. Asking ***here*** isn't the first place to visit.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where you encounter those situations, the questions may find a home in existing sites already:

- the various language sites across the network
- [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)
- [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)
- [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com)

A question like

> Is there a culture where you say "hello" by spitting on people?

wouldn't fit, but it reminds me of the following sentence which is present in *every* Help Center across the network:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

([source](/help/dont-ask))

Even a site like [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) is about problems faced while building a world for a story/game/etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! By this, does the following question belong to interpersonal skills? "Is it okay not to have a separate BBQ device for people who are vegan or doing Ramadan?" as well "Why did my Masai friend asked to spit at him at  our workplace during his afterwork birthday party last night?" should go to Workplace? exaggerated example but other absurd things could indeed happen

Comment: @J.Doe - Every SE site has a help page that tries to explain what is on-topic for that site. I don't frequent the Interpersonal Skills exchange, but [here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a link to their page. Based on a cursory read there, I would assume the answer to your first question is yes.